# What is the role of PAGE section in windows Drivers?

Tags: windows, pe, kernel

I have seen many drivers with a section named PAGE, but couldn't find good enough information on it, what is the role of this section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, it's a section that will supposedly be mapped as [paged memory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-pools). This can contain code or data and is governed by [the PAGED_CODE macro](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/mm-bad-pointer#paged_code), among others, at source code level.

That is, whatever gets stored in that section cannot be accessed at arbitrary IRQLs. Quote:

> If the IRQL > APC_LEVEL, the PAGED_CODE macro causes the system to ASSERT.

Also see [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/overview-of-windows-memory-space) for an entry point into the overall topic. But I reckon given the specific nature of your question you are aware of paged and nonpaged pool and so on.